# React Component gets values from props and state only on second click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, react-state

I have error with my component showing up without values from props when i open it first. When i click to open this component second time values from props have arrived correctly and component is displayed correctly. There is no automatic update in my component when props arrive. Is there somehting to do with my `componentWillReceiveProps()` mehtod or where could error actually lie?

It is quite nested relationship between that i have created but here are my components to update state and receive props:

```
class UserRegistrations extends React.Component {

    state = {
        registrations: []
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const userID = this.props.token
        axios.get(`/api/userregistrationslist/${userID}`)
                    .then(res => {
                        this.setState({
                            registrations: res.data
                        })
                        console.log('Kasutaja regamised1', res.data)
                    });
    }

    render(){
        return(<ListView reg={this.state.registrations} />)
    }
}

class Event extends React.Component {
    render() {
    return(<div><TrainingCard id={this.props.id.event}/></div>)
    }
}

class ListView extends React.Component {

    state = {
       regs: []
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps() {
        const reg = this.props.reg
        console.log('Propid1', this.props.reg)
        this.setState({
            regs: reg.map((registration) => <Event key={registration.id} id={registration} />)
        }, () => console.log('final regs', this.state.regs))
    }

    render(){
    return(<ul>{this.state.regs}</ul>)
    }
}
```

And here is my TrainingCard component where props get inserted:

```
class TrainingCard extends React.Component {
    state = {
        training: {}
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const trainingID = this.props.id
        console.log('Item training props', this.props.id)
        axios.get(`/api/${trainingID}/`)
            .then(res => {
                this.setState({
                    training: res.data
                })
                console.log('Componendi data', res.data)
            })
    }

    render(){
    return(<div className='trainingCard' ><Card title={this.state.training.title} style={{ width: 300 }}>
    <p>Spordiala: {this.state.training.sport}</p>
    <p>Asukoht: {this.state.training.location}</p>
    <p><a href={`trainings/${this.state.training.id}`}>Link treeningule</a></p></Card></div>)
    }
}

export default TrainingCard;
```

Comment: Wjhy do ListView and TrainingCard have state? you're just passing that state from the parent, just use props instead/?

Comment: Because in TrainingCard i make API call and i want to place fetched data into my state.

Comment: It's not clear what do you mean by "open a component for the 2nd time", and which values are exactly missing. Is `this.props.id` missing from `TrainingCard` in `componentDidMount`?

Comment: i have specific url to my component and this url is connected to button. When i click button it takes me to that component. When i first time click to that button i only see in my console log fetched data that is under componentDidMount method in UserRegistrations class.

Comment: I can't see the error just from the code, but I'd suggest you switch to react hooks (have a look at `useEffect`) & functional components. In this case, the code will be shorter & easier to read.